# Is a free proton a positive Hydrogen-1 ion?

Tags: hydrogen, protons, ions, isotopes

The Hydrogen-1 isotope is a form of hydrogen with 1 electron, 1 proton, and 0 neutrons.  If that isotope were to lose its electron (thus being a Hydrogen-1 ion with a positive charge) what would be the different between it and a free proton?  The positive Hydrogen-1 would contain 0 electrons, 1 proton, and 0 neutrons and the free proton would obviously contain only 1 proton.  Is there a defining factor that would distinguish between a free proton and positive Hydrogen-1 ion?

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: _...is there a defining factor?..._  No.  A proton is a proton is an H+ ion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diameter of nuclei of Hydrogen atom is in the range of $1.75$ fm. You might think that, the proton lies inside this boundary in case of positive hydrogen-1 ion and the free proton doesn't have any definite boundary. It is not the case, the diameter of the nuclei of hydrogen atom is nothing but the diameter of the proton. So, there is no difference between positive hydrogen-1 ion and a free proton.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for an answer within the "physics field", that I'm afraid I won't be able to answer satisfactorily. However, if it is the case that you have encountered this nomenclature within physical-chemistry, theoretical chemistry or simply general chemistry papers (or even biochemical ones) this, the "H+", notation is usually a short way of representing the H3O+ molecule, yield from a free hydrogen cation (which in fact would be the same as a proton, deuteron and triton in its respective isotopic concentrations) and a molecule of water (H2O), sometimes the "H+" can represent H5O2+ or H9O4+, or the respective solvated forms; when talking about protons as particles chemists tend to say "free hydrogen cation" or "free proton". So within the context of chemistry they are different things.

I may also suggest you to look into the Thomas Fermi Density Functional Theory model based upon the uniform electron gas (it is not strictly related to the question but perhaps you, or any enthusiast of particle physics with application to chemistry, will find it interesting).

Answer (score -1):

1. In the NEBULA, ionized hydrogen gas in plasma in free space has the electrons freed to higher orbits and emits radiations as follows: Lyman series (n′ = 1); Balmer series (n′ = 2); Paschen series ( n' = 3); Brackett series (n′ = 4); Pfund series (n′ = 5).
2. ELECTROLYTES IN SOLUTION: Ionized cation hydrogen in liquid with hydroxil anions are present.
3. COSMIC RAYS: Q: Is free proton same as H+ ion? Answer: No. Free protons are present in high energy cosmic rays, and they tend to form an electron shell in the instant the energy level comes down.